# How to remote desktop to a redhat cloud computer

Tags: cloud, remote-desktop, redhat

I have a computer running in the cloud.  It is using redhat.  Currently I can only log into using putty/terminal.  I'd like to be able to see a desktop and GUI and access the computer through a program such as remote desktop (from a windows machine).  What do I need to install and configure to enable remote desktop on this computer running redhat?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try a remote desktop solution like [NoMachine(NX) Free Edition](http://www.nomachine.com/) or VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use the windows remote desktop client, install [xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/).